# Pass an array generated in Google Apps Script to a HTML page and using for basic navigation

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

I have a simple function who retrieves data from a spreadsheet and passes this array to a modal window.

```
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('sheet1'); 
var data = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
const htmlForModal = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("detailedView");
htmlForModal.DATA = data;
htmlForModal.rowIndex = 0; // starts with the first array

const htmlOutput = htmlForModal.evaluate();
return ui.showModalDialog(htmlOutput, "title");
```

Obviously data is an array of arrays.

Inside the HTML I can use DATA values through scriptlets like this:

```
<p id="title">
                    <?= DATA[rowIndex][4] ?>
</p>
```

and it works. The problem is that I need a system to navigate through the array. A simple "NEXT" button  to update the paragraph with a new rowIndex (rowIndex+1) each time I click it. I know I can use document.queryselector to change the innerHTML of my paragraph, but ho can I change `<?= DATA[rowIndex][4] ?>` with `<?= DATA[rowIndex+1][4] ?>` ?

I tried a console.log at the beginning of the HTML for logging DATA and it is filled correctly. BUT it appears to be a string of text, not an array. If DATA renders only the first time, is there a method to rebuild the array when loading HTML and making it available for scripts inside the HTML?

Possibly I would avoid a call to google.script.run. I tried it and it works but each time I click the button it has to call google script, load the row and return it... and it is sooo slow :-( While passing the entire array into the html is fast...

Can you help me? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should request all the data from the client side once using `google.script.run` ([see docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#top_of_page)), save it, and change the page layout using JavaScript when the user changes the page without requesting the data again. [See best practices about asynchronously loading vs adding data using templates](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#load_data_asynchronously_not_in_templates).

```js
// Code.gs snippet

function showDialog() {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('detailedView')
      .evaluate();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  return ui.showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Dialog title');
}

function getData() {
  // Example based on the question code
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('sheet1');
  var data = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  return data.map(function (value) {
    return value[4];
  })
}
```

```html
<!-- detailedView.html snippet -->

<script type="text/javascript">
  var data;
  function onGetData(d) {
    // Save the result in the global variable
    data = d;

    // the call to load the first page (change it to fit your code)
    loadPage(0);
  }
  
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(onGetData)
    .getData();
</script>
```

I'd also recommended you to have a `loading...` message by default, so the user knows that the data is being processed.

### References

- [Documentation for `google.script.run`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#top_of_page)
- [HTML Service: Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices)

Comment: Martì, first of all thank you very much for your answer. I think we are near the solution but I would need more help...

1) where do I have to put the script of detaildeView? In the <head> section, before the </body> tag or it makes no difference?
2) I suppose google.script.run won't run unless I put it into a function and load this function with an onload event. Is it right?
3) I don't understand the loadPage command. If it's jquery I'm not using jQuery in my script...

I tried putting the google.script.run into a function and calling it onload. It calls the function but it fails...

Comment: Ok, I made some steps ahead :-) I put the script in the <head> tag, I run the script through a function called by body onload. It works :-). But what if I need to map other values than value[4]? If I map an array of arrays (i.e. [value[1],value[2],value[3],value[4]] ) how can I retrieve those values (by row and column) into HTML?

Comment: `loadPage(0)` it was a place holder for your code that shows the user the first page. It's not defined and should not work.

Comment: As for the the map, it's not necessary. You question was only using the forth element and that's why I added the map. You can send the entire `data` to have it available on the client side.

Comment: Ok. But how can I retrieve data (unmapped) values inside HTML? In getData() I simply changed the last part with "return data;". How do I have to change onGetData() to return the array of arrays? If I console.log("data") it says "data is null".

Comment: OOOOK, I found the solution: my data array contains a "date" value. And dates are not permitted. Reference here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#parameters. Once I transform this value with Utilities.formatDate all works perfectly :-)
Thank you Martì