Using HTML as a popup window to help move data from one sheet to another
I have an excel spread sheet that used a macro and a user form to help move data from one sheet to another.  I'm trying to recreate this in Google Sheets.
I found this information but it just seems to be snippets, I'm looking for more of a full "here's what to do" answer.  //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65321897/pass-an-array-generated-in-google-apps-script-to-a-html-page-and-using-for-basic.  This post seems to show how to get the data from gs to the HTML but how can the data be displayed and used?
Basically I have 2 ranges of data.  Range one is a 3 column 4180 row set of data that I wish to move from, I can pass 3 variables to the HTML and not the whole range.  Range two is where the data will be moved to, it contains a similar structure 3 columns 109 rows but the date of the data move will be logged in a fourth column.
With the Excel user form I have a drop box to select if I wish to move it to the top section or the bottom section of the hold rack, then I type in the text box the slot I wish to put it in.  The user form will show a message of "Slot Open" or "Slot Full".  When I press the move button the data gets transferred from one sheet to the other and the date is auto populated.

Looking for an option that will replicate a user form from Excel.
